# Passing variables from PHP script to procedure Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Mysql Stored Procedure:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `flux_zilnic` (motiv,nume_client,data_inregistrare,ora_inregistrare,status_alocare,ora_alocare,status_preluare,ora_preluare,status_rezolvare,ora_rezolvare,operator,birou,fisa_service)
SELECT  '',nume_client,data_inregistrare,ora_inregistrare,'ALOCAT','$ora_alocare','','','','','$operator','BIROUL 2',''
FROM `tableta` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

UPDATE `birouri` SET `disponibilitate` = 'OCUPAT' WHERE `birouri`.`username` = '$operator';

DELETE FROM `tableta` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
END
```

PHP Script calling the procedure:

```
//CODE HERE
$operator = "user_name";
$current_date = date_create('');
$ora_alocare = date_format($current_date, 'H:i');
//CODE HERE
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "CALL allocateClients()");
//CODE HERE
```

How can I pass the variables $operator, $ora_alocare to the Mysql Stored Procedure? I can`t find any good answer troughout Google.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `procedureExample` $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE `procedureExample`(IN ora_alocare_param TIME,in operator_param varchar(20))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `flux_zilnic` (motiv,nume_client,data_inregistrare,ora_inregistrare,status_alocare,ora_alocare,status_preluare,ora_preluare,status_rezolvare,ora_rezolvare,operator,birou,fisa_service)
SELECT  '',nume_client,data_inregistrare,ora_inregistrare,'ALOCAT',ora_alocare_param,'','','','',operator_param,'BIROUL 2',''
FROM `tableta` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

UPDATE `birouri` SET `disponibilitate` = 'OCUPAT' WHERE `birouri`.`username` = operator_param;

DELETE FROM `tableta` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

       END $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

**PHP**

```
$call = mysqli_prepare($connection, 'CALL procedureExample(?, ?)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($call, 'ss',$ora_alocare, $operator);
mysqli_stmt_execute($call);
```